# Generic T - create new instance

Tags: c#, generics

I have a function to deserialize any type of object that I get from the Api. 
 If there is an error, I want to return a new object of type T.

I tried to do it with `return new T()`, but I get the error:

> 'T' must be a non-abstract type with a public parameterless
>   constructor in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or
>   method

What's wrong with my code?

```
[SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2202:Do not dispose objects multiple times")]
        internal static T DeserializeObject<T>(this JsonSerializer serializer, string value) 
        {
            try
            {
                using (var stringReader = new StringReader(value))
                {
                    using (var jsonTextReader = new JsonTextReader(stringReader))
                    {
                        return (T)serializer.Deserialize(jsonTextReader, typeof(T));
                    }
                }
            }

            catch {

                return GetDefault<T>(); //This line returns the error
            }  
        }


        public static T GetDefault<T>() where T : new()
        {
            if (typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T)))
            {
                return new T();
            }
            return default(T);
        }
```

Comment: @Cody Gray Did you not see? He already uses the type constraint! The problem is a different one

Comment: @adjan OP is only using the type constraint in one place. The line with the error is in the method without type constraint. So it's still a duplicate.

Comment: @Stijn but where does the other question say this is a requirement to have it in every method?

Comment: @adjan the paragraph below the first code block in the answer explains that.

Comment: @AndersonPimentel I am aware of that. I just don't see where the duplicate answer explains that.

Comment: @Stijn Where? I don't see it?

Comment: @Cody Gray I edited the answer to something I consider a good one. I could not provide an answer myself because you have closed it for no reason.

Comment: agree with @adjan, it's actually not a duplicate and so voted to reopen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `DeserializeObject<T>` you are calling

```
GetDefault<T>()
```

which has the type parameter constraint `where T : new()`, but `DeserializeObject<T>`'s `T` is unconstrained. You have to add the constraint to `DeserializeObject<T>` as well:

```
internal static T DeserializeObject<T>(this JsonSerializer serializer, string value) : where T : new()
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked

Comment: @adjan I admit I was answering with Visual Studio closed. =) Just deleted the comment.

Comment: @Rahul I see that and now I got it. Just deleted the comment.

Comment: @adjan, appreciate your edit in answer. Thanks

Comment: @Rahul Sure. But I don't appreciate people closing questions for the wrong reason (not accusing you obv)

Comment: @adjan, make sense and am pretty sure that they didn't actually understood the question probably